# Is the fuzzy conjunction function continuous?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

As the question states, is the fuzzy conjunction (t-norm) function continuous? This was an exam question, the answer was no, but looking at the conjunctions we studied, this seems to be the case:

[image]

However, working from the definition of a fuzzy conjunction, I cannot prove that they are continuous always. What am I missing? Is there a (trivial) counter example?

Comment: The "drastic" one is clearly not continuous.

Comment: @Samuel D'oh! I'm an idiot! Thanks!